# Play! Framework inconsistent filter behaviour

Tags: scala, playframework

In the Play! framework 2.1.x I'm seeing an inconsistent order of execution given the contents of a request. This is causing some problems with request gating code I'm trying to implement.

Consider the following sample code consisting of a Filter, an Action wrapper and an Action.

```
object AFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextAction: EssentialAction) : EssentialAction = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(request: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] = {
        def readBody(nextA: EssentialAction, request: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] = {

          def step(body: Array[Byte], nextI: Iteratee[Array[Byte],
              Result]) (i: Input[Array[Byte]]): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] = i match {
            case Input.EOF =>
              System.err.println("test 1")
              Iteratee.flatten(nextI.feed(Input.EOF))
            case Input.Empty =>
              Cont[Array[Byte], Result](step(body, nextI) _)
            case Input.El(e) =>
              val curBody = Array.concat(body, e)
              Cont[Array[Byte], Result](step(curBody,
                Iteratee.flatten(nextI.feed(Input.El(e)))) _)
          }

          val nextIteratee: Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] = nextA(request)

          Cont[Array[Byte], Result](i => step(Array(), nextIteratee)(i))
        }

      readBody(nextAction,request)
    }
  }
}


def testActionWrapper[A](action: Action[A]): Action[A] = {
  Action(action.parser) {
    request => Async {
      System.err.println("test 2")
      Future.successful(action(request))
    }
  }
}
def testAction =
    testActionWrapper {
      System.err.println("test 3")
      Action(parse.empty) { request =>
        System.err.println("test 4")
        Async {
          System.err.println("test 5")
          Future.successful(Ok("Ok"))
        }
      }
    }
```

With a POST, PUT or a GET with a body and parse.json the order of the println execution is

test 3, test 1, test 2, test 4, test 5

Other than the fact that "test 3" happens first this is what I expected, the filter iteratee completes before the action wrapper executes. But with a simple GET with no body I see this

test 3, test 2, test 1, test 4, test 5

The action wrapper is executing before the filter iteratee completes. This is likely because the Action skips execution of it's own body parsing iteratee.

Now my question, the best way to deal with this is to also skip the iteratee in the case of no body? Or, perhaps more to the point, does this mean that in the highly concurrent world of Scala Play! there is simply no guarantee that a Filter must complete before an Action executes?

Comment: Are you *certain* that the order is exactly as your `println`s suggest? Remember `System.out` can be buffered - try using `System.err.println` to confirm?

Comment: That's true, but I saw this behaviour while trying to do something else and recreated it using println to help explain what I was seeing. Just to be sure, though, I changed to using System.err.println and got the same results.